# Typescript type unions not detecting correct types with typeguards

Tags: typescript, react-typescript, typeguards

I have types like this:

```
type NodeDataChildren =
  | {
      type: NodeDataChildType;
    }
  | {
      type: NodeDataChildType.CHOICES;
      choices?: Array<NodeDataChildChoice>;
    };

export enum NodeDataChildType {
  CHOICES = "choices",
  TEXT = "text",
  CONTINUE = "continue",
  NONE = "none",
}
export type NodeDataChildChoice = {
  id: string;
  value: string;
};
```

But when I write code like this, the type guard that checks for explicit type:

```
// React
        {data.children.type === NodeDataChildType.CHOICES && (
          <MainNodeUI choices={data.children.choices} addNewBranch={addNewBranch} />
        )}
```

Typescript throws this error:

```
Property 'choices' does not exist on type 'NodeDataChildren'.
  Property 'choices' does not exist on type '{ type: NodeDataChildType; }'
```

Answer (score 0):

The minute I posted this question, I found about super helpful typescript utility:  `Exclude<>`

The problem in the above code is that `NodeDataChildType.CHOICES` is not a unique identifier as this type also contains this enum value:

```
{
      type: NodeDataChildType;
}
```

The solution is to explicitly tell typescript which enum values are allowed on which types, like this:

```
type NodeDataChildren =
 | {
      type: Exclude<NodeDataChildType, NodeDataChildType.CHOICES>;
 }
| {
      type: NodeDataChildType.CHOICES;
      choices?: Array<NodeDataChildChoice>;
};
```